# using REPLACE in MySQL Query just isn't working

Tags: mysql

Quick background, I have a small database with a table named 'songs'.  This table holds the title, artist and URL of music I have on my machine.  Several of the single quotes have been dropped from the track title (for example, the don't is stored as dont) and I'm attempting to replace them.  I just cannot get this query to affect any rows:

```
UPDATE Songs
SET Title = REPLACE (Title, 'dont', 'don\'t')
```

No love.  Isn't this correct syntax?  It tells me that 0 rows were updated.
If it helps, I'm running version 5.5.27.  I know there are a couple hundred rows with improper donts in there...  I'm about to dump the results into Notepad and do a find/replace on don't and just run an update statement that way, but it's kinda hacky.  Any ideas friends?

A couple of sample rows:

```
"51","Dont Stay Home","311","311 Greatest Hits","Rap","E:\Music\311\311GreatestHits\dontstayhome.mp3"
"229","Dont Turn Around","Ace Of Base","The Very Best Of","Dance","E:\Music\AceofBase\VeryBestOf\03-ace_of_base-dont_turn_around.mp3"
```

The Fields in order are id, title, artist, album, genre, path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it like this

```
UPDATE Songs
    SET Title = REPLACE(Title, 'Dont', 'Don\'t');
                                ^       ^
```

The reason for that is

> **[`REPLACE(str,from_str,to_str)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)**
>
> Returns the string str with all occurrences of the string from_str
>   replaced by the string to_str. **REPLACE() performs a case-sensitive
>   match when searching for from_str**.

If you want to replace either case you can do

```
UPDATE Songs 
   SET Title = REPLACE(REPLACE(Title, 'Dont', 'Don\'t'), 'dont', 'don\'t')
 WHERE Title LIKE '%dont%' -- it makes sense to limit update to only those rows that have dont in it no matter case
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/92b78/1)** demo

Comment: One internet for you good sir!  Thank you.  I totally missed the case sensitive part of that function description.  I feel like a tool now!  I'd upvote you too if I had enough of a rep!  Now I'm off to answer some questions of my own so I can upvote you at a later date!

Answer (score 0):

The first thought is that there might be some invisible characters.  What does the following return?

```
select *
from songs
where title like '%dont%';
```

EDIT:

I didn't notice this at first.  The problem is the space after the function name.  Try this:

```
UPDATE Songs
    SET Title = REPLACE(Title, 'dont', 'don\'t');
```

This is explained in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/functions.html):

> Note
>
> By default, there must be no whitespace between a function name and
>   the parenthesis following it. This helps the MySQL parser distinguish
>   between function calls and references to tables or columns that happen
>   to have the same name as a function. However, spaces around function
>   arguments are permitted.

EDIT II:

I don't know if the collation has an effect.  But you can also try using double quotes as the string delimiter:

```
UPDATE Songs
    SET Title = REPLACE(Title, 'dont', "don't");
```

Comment: I'm sure there are rows that need updating.  Using this query I got back 99 rows:
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Songs
WHERE Title LIKE '%dont%'

Comment: Tried that as well.  Tried all caps on the function name, tried lower case.  Tried matching case for Title~title, tried space after function, tried no space after function.  Tried with delimiter character ; afterwards, tried without.

Comment: how about a couple of sample rows that the above query didn't update?

Comment: If it helps, that field is a varchar(255) and holds latin1_swedish_ci collation (I don't believe I set this at design time).

Comment: Also gave the double quotes as string delimiter, without success.  Thanks for the help and advice so far...